# Making largest line in 10 × 10 grid.

Tags: combinatorics, path-connected, multigrid

How many blocks can you pass through at most in a 10 × 10 grid.
The Rules are
1. U cannot go over a line
2. You cannot lift the pencil.
**3. You cannot allow the blocks you have passed through to make a 2×2 block of adjacent boxes**
I think it would be 71.
[image]

Comment: This would be better on puzzling.se

Comment: Answered [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95279/making-longest-line-in-10-by-10-grid).